# Make a Mongoose schema field read-only

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongoose "User" schema, and one of the fields needs to be read-only. (the "accounts" field can be updated externally, so I don't want updates to the User to overwrite the changes.)

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
firstName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    default: '',
    validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your first name']
},
lastName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    default: '',
    validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your last name']
},
displayName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
},
email: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    default: '',
    validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your email'],
    match: [/.+\@.+\..+/, 'Please fill a valid email address']
},
username: {
    type: String,
    unique: 'Username already exists',
    required: 'Please fill in a username',
    trim: true
},
password: {
    type: String,
},
accounts: [{
        account_hash: {type: String},
        account_name: {type: String}        
    }],

updated: {
    type: Date
},
created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
}
}
```

I've seen answers recommending making the field virtual, but on save, the field gets removed from Mongo. Is there an easy way to make specific fields in a Mongoose schema read-only?

Comment: Do you want the `accounts` field to be `read-only` (or) want to prevent the user from updating it (and allowing someone else to do the update) ?

Comment: Can you provide more details on how exactly the updates should work? Because you mention it gets updated `externally` (not sure what that means) but not `internally`? Update is an update to the field ... what differentiates the update type?

Comment: By externally I mean someone may manually update the data directly in Mongo, and I don't want that data to be overwritten by a user.save... So I want the User schema to always GET data from the Mongo store, but never save the accounts field back to the store.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: [mastoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mastoose)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to me your best bet is the `pre` [middleware](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) for `save/update`.

You can check if the fields you **do not want** changed are being changed with `isModified` and simply throw error about your fields being read only from there:

```
someSchema.pre('save', function(next) { 
  if(this.isModified('someField')) {
    throw 'someField is read only!'
  }
  else {
    next();
  }
});
```

For update you should be getting the updates via `this.getUpdate()` and look in there for your fields.

Answer (score 13):

With the latest version of Mongoose, you can set 'immutable' as a property on the the field that you want to be immutable.
You can read more here [Mongoose immutable](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-immutable).

So you can do something like

```
const schema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, immutable: true },
  age: Number
});

const Model = mongoose.model('Test', schema);

await Model.create({ name: 'test' });
const doc = await Model.findOne();

doc.isNew; // false
doc.name = 'new name';
doc.name; // 'test', because `name` is immutable
```

The downside to this is that your users will not get an error message that lets them know that the field they're trying to update or have updated is read only